# How do I place the values in one column into a comma-delimited variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with values that I would like to use as column names in a dynamic PIVOT query. As such, I need to put the values into a comma-delimited string (and then into a variable).

In other words, I have a table @ColumnData like this:

```
ID      Title
1       Income 
2       Rent 
3       Utilities   
4       Childcare
```

And I need a the column "Title" in this form:

```
@Variable = [Income],[Rent],[Utilities],[Childcare]
```

Comment: Why on earth does all the world swear by **dynamic SQL** instead of using a reporting tool? You have to admit that the only reason to implement what you are trying to achieve is "reporting". SSRS is a reasonable tool that comes with SQL Server and perfectly solves this kind of problem. It can format your result nicely, just display it, export it to several destination formats or even send it via email.

Comment: @WolfgangK Unfortunately SSRS isn't an option in this case... This stored procedure is being used to generate a report through a website if that makes any sense.

Comment: SSRS generates web reports that can be embedded in web pages using a Report Viewer Control. But of course it's up to you to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FOR XML PATH('')` to concatenate:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Title VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #Tbl(Title) VALUES ('Income'), ('Rent'), ('Utilities'), ('Childcare');

DECLARE @ColumnDate VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @ColumnDate = 
    STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Title)
        FROM #Tbl
        ORDER BY ID
        FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @ColumnDate;

DROP TABLE #Tbl;
```